# Some Variables not getting rendered in jenkins pipeline inside single quotes

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

I am using below code  in CASE 1 in my jenkins library  , it is able to render the artifactory password and username  inside the sh block but not able to render the variable docker_repo , if I replace it with code in CASE 2 it works fine but it is an unsafe practice , Any idea why it is happening ? and how to overcome it ?

CASE 1

```
def dockerAuth(String creds = 'mysecret',String docker_repo = ARTF_URL) {
    withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: creds,
                     usernameVariable: 'ARTIFACTORY_USER',
                     passwordVariable: 'ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD')]) {
        //opts = '-u $ARTIFACTORY_USER -p $ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD'
        sh 'sudo docker login -u $ARTIFACTORY_USER -p $ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD $docker_repo'


    }
}
```

CASE 2

```
def dockerAuth(String creds = 'mysecret',String docker_repo = ARTF_URL) {
        withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: creds,
                         usernameVariable: 'ARTIFACTORY_USER',
                         passwordVariable: 'ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD')]) {
            //opts = '-u $ARTIFACTORY_USER -p $ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD'
            sh "sudo docker login -u ${ARTIFACTORY_USER} -p ${ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD} ${docker_repo}"
    
    
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

I solved it using below code ,
converted docker_repo into a env variable and then used inside single quotes.
Reason for using single quotes in sh is in this link https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/admin-resources/latest/automating-with-jenkinsfile/string-interpolation

If anyone has a better answer please post

```
def dockerAuth(String creds = 'jenkins-artifactory',String docker_repo = "${ARTF_SECURE_DOCKER_URL}") {
    withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: creds,
                     usernameVariable: 'ARTIFACTORY_USER',
                     passwordVariable: 'ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD')]) {
        withEnv(["repo=${docker_repo}"]) {
        sh 'sudo docker login -u $ARTIFACTORY_USER -p $ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD $repo'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need "CASE 3", where you use double quotes (as case 2) but escape the dollar on environment variables, but leave it for templating groovy variables

```
    sh "sudo docker login -u \${ARTIFACTORY_USER} -p \${ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD} ${docker_repo}"
```

Comment: If i use "opts" which is commented in my case 2 inside my sh , then also it ll work but just i want to know why it doesnt render docker_repo inside single quotes ?

Comment: Because docker_repo is a local variable, not passed to the environment, and string templating in groovy requires double quotes. Single quotes are for literal strings

Comment: Issue is if u use above method then it ll still lead to security issues as per this link , i want to know how i can use it in single quotes https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/admin-resources/latest/automating-with-jenkinsfile/string-interpolation

Comment: The repo URL is a security issue?

Comment: what about injection via docker_repo? It is root call via sudo so if you provide repository name like
docker_repo="repo.com;ls /root"
You can run other commands too. more abt it is given in the link https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/admin-resources/latest/automating-with-jenkinsfile/string-interpolation

Comment: thanks your comment abt local variable helped me to write below code

Answer (score 1):

Also you can try this

```
def dockerAuth(String creds = 'mysecret',String docker_repo = ARTF_URL) {
    withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: creds,
                     usernameVariable: 'ARTIFACTORY_USER',
                     passwordVariable: 'ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD')]) {
        //opts = '-u $ARTIFACTORY_USER -p $ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD'
        sh 'sudo docker login -u $ARTIFACTORY_USER -p $ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD' + " ${docker_repo}"
    }
}
```

Comment: Please consider to improve your answer with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71693784/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).